# Why am I getting an Extra page at the End of my SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have tried everything I've found online - adding up total of margins + tablix width < page width, etc.  Nothing I've tried works.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Can you post the XML code from your report? If you open the .rdl file in Notepad, you can see the XML.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.